# Ionic / AngularJS menubar refresh button to current view's controller

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

We're building an Ionic app with AngularJS. This app has a menubar on top of the screen with a button to open the side/hamburger-menu and a refresh button.

The menu is in a separate HTML-file and has it's own controller which makes the current menu-item active.

In app.js the states are defined for which view has which controller.

The menubar has a refresh button in the right-top corner, but how can I make that button (which has the same controller as the menu) call a function on the scope of the controller for the current view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this through [`events`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Template linked to Controller A:

```
...
<a href="#" ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</a>
...
```

Controller A:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.refresh = function() {
        // Your refresh code
        $rootScope.$emit('refreshedPressed');
    }

}
```

Controller B:

```
.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

   $rootScope.$on('refreshedPressed', function() {
       // Handle the event.
   });

}
```

Comment: Where Controller A is the menu-controller and Controller B any other controller for a view?

Comment: Yes, in your case you would place the $rootScope.$emit in your menu controller (where you can reach the refresh button) and the $rootScope.$on in a different controller where you want to respond to that event.